# Inconsistency with "View all..." link arrow style for badges block on the profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, badges

There's inconsistency with "View all..." link arrow style on the [profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile):

> [image: different arrows]

P.S. this post was originally accidentally posted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368344/339911). Now deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no issue with arrows anymore:

> [image]